# Lucene .NET searching

Tags: c#, search, autocomplete, lucene, lucene.net

Hi i am trying to make autocomplete system using Lucene library to search over 170K records.

But there is a litle problem.

For example when i search for Candice Gra(...), it brings records like

```
Candice Jackson
Candice Hamilton
Candice Hayes
```

Bu not  `Candice Graham` to make Lucene find `Candice Graham` i need to type `Candice Graham` exactly.

Here is the code that i'm building query.

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(context.Server.MapPath("
ISet<string> stopWordSet = new HashSet<string>(stopWords);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, stopWordSet);

IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
Searcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

//Singe Field Search
var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30,
                        "Title",
                        analyzer);
string strQuery = string.Format("{0}", q);
var query = queryParser.Parse(strQuery);
```

If i build strQuery like this (* appended to the query)

```
string strQuery = string.Format("{0}*", q);
```

But using this way brings irrelevant records too.
For example if i search Candice Gra(...) again it returns records like

```
Grass
Gravity
Gray (etc.)
```

By the way i used KeywordAnalyzer and SimpleAnalyzer but these are not worked either.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape your spaces if you want them included in the search;

```
var query = queryParser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(strQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put a AND keyword between these two words.

"Candice" AND "Gra"

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#AND